# Minimizing $ \langle (Ax -b ), (Ax -b ) \rangle $

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I want to find vector $x$ that minimizes $   \langle  (Ax -b ),  (Ax -b ) \rangle  $
namely minimizes the inner product of the error $(Ax -b )$ with itself. Is it possible to do so even if I don't have the exact definition of the inner product function $\langle  ., . \rangle $ and I just know it satisfies  the rules of an inner product function ?
The $n \times n $ matrix A is known and so the n dimentional vector $b$

Comment: No, the answer depends on the inner product.

Comment: But can you craft an expression for the minimum using the inner product without knowing exactly what is it ?

Comment: Let $A^T$ be the transpose in respect to the given inner product, just solve $$A^TAx=A^tb.$$

Comment: What  does it  mean a transpose with respect to the inner product ?  Do  you assume the inner product is a dot product ? I wonder what happens if this is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're discussing matrices and vectors, I'll assume that this is an inner product over $\Bbb R^n$. A similar line of reasoning can be applied for the case of $\Bbb C^n$.

Every inner product over $\Bbb R^n$ can be written in the form $\langle x,y \rangle = x^TPy$ for some (symmetric) positive definite matrix $P$. Given such a $P$, write $P$ in the form $P = M^TM$ (this can be done using a [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) for instance). Our goal is to minimize the quantity
$$
\begin{align}
\langle Ax-b,Ax - b \rangle &= (Ax - b)^TP(Ax - b)
\\ & = (Ax - b)^TM^TM(Ax - b)
\\ & = [M(Ax - b)]^T[M(Ax - b)]
= (MAx - Mb)^T(MAx - Bb).
\end{align}
$$
However, minimizing this quantity simply amounts to the usual least squares. That is, we are simply looking for the least-squares solution, relative to the standard inner product, of $MAx = Mb$.  Thus, $x$ is a solution to the problem iff it satisfies
$$
(MA)^T(MA)x = (MA)^TMb \implies\\
A^T(M^TM)Ax = A^T(M^TM)b \implies
A^TPAx = A^TPb.
$$
So, it turns out that we didn't need the decomposition of $P$ after all!

If $A$ has linearly independent columns, then the unique minimizer is given by
$$
x = (A^TPA)^{-1}A^TPb.
$$
In the more general case, one such minimizer can be found via the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse. In particular, one solution is $x = (A^TPA)^+A^TPb$.

Comment: Thanks that exactly what I was looking for!